# Setting path for replica set different from root in windows doesnt work

Tags: mongodb, windows-10

As I created replicaSet outside of /data/db folder by mistake, so I would like to set path to folder which is not root where I created replica set, instead of starting again.

I tried this(inside mongodb-instance folder is 3 replica folders):

```
"D:\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath D:\mongodb-instance
```

then I try to run It:

```
mongod --replSet "rs0"
```

but still got the same problem:

> Data directory C:\data\db\ not found.

Answer (score 0):

For replication, you need to setup multiple servers. Then each of them will have their own data folders.
Then start the servers using command

```
mongod --host <hostname> --port <portNum> --replSet "nameOfReplicaSet"
```

Once all the servers are running you'll have to initiate the replication by connecting to any one of them and execute the `rs.initiate(replConfig)` command with whatever configuration you need.
You can refer to the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/).

Comment: uf I dont get it really well. this link you provide me, I used something similar to create replicas. then I didnt make it in \data\db but when I fix it, 'mongod --replSet "rs0" ' would just create bunch of files in \data\db same files as each replica has. so I really dont get how to start replicas again, I could do it only first time that I created them. hm, for sake of practice I am doing everything on 1 pc.if I have more than 1 pc, then what would be hostname and port ?

Comment: hostname will be the ipaddress of other PCs.

Comment: If you are using a single PC, have you created multiple mongo servers on different ports and gave each server different data folders to store data to?

Comment: yes I am using different ports for each replica, you may see it in my previous question where you also answered. I dont have data inserted yet. I just want to re-run my replica and get same output after rs.status() as I did when I created replicas. thanks for helping !

Comment: You can restart all the servers with mongd --port [portnum] --replSet "rs0".
After that connect to any server and try to run rs.status()